# Parsing .ini file with configparser - getting errors - wrong format of file

Tags: python, config, ini

I would like to parse an *.ini file with ConfigParser with Python 2.6. The *.ini file structure looks like this:

```
>> Created by 1111
>> Date of creation: 2015.07.07
>> PlatForm: MS

[aaaa]
Author="bababa"
Version="22222"
[--]

[DIRECTORY]
v="c:\d\a\"
b="c:\d\b\"
n="c:\d\c\"
m="c:\d\e\"
z="c:\d\f\"
[--]
```

And configparser returns error because of the beginning of the file `ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.`

Can I somehow fix this without modifying *.ini file?

Comment: You can pass an open file handle to [`readfp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp), so you could skip the first three lines manually *then* pass it in.

Comment: What does the `>>` sequence supposed to mean?

Comment: This is not valid syntax. Use `;` to indicate a comment.

Comment: How can I trim my file without saving all lines to string and skip three first?

Comment: Do as @jonrsharpe suggested then.

Comment: readline three times and then pass the handle to readfp as in jonrsharpe comment

Comment: Thank you user341245125412412412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ConfigParser
file = open('config.ini')
file.readline()
file.readline()
file.readline()
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(file)
```

for `Python 2.6`